# Possible compiler bug in MSVC12 (VS2013) with designated initializer

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, compiler-bug, designated-initializer, msvc12

Using VS2013 Update 2, I've stumbled on some strange error message :

```
// test.c
int main(void)
{
    struct foo {
        int i;
        float f;
    };

    struct bar {
        unsigned u;
        struct foo foo;
        double d;
    };

    struct foo some_foo = {
        .i = 1,
        .f = 2.0
    };

    struct bar some_bar = {
        .u = 3,

// error C2440 : 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'foo' to 'int'
        .foo = some_foo,

        .d = 4.0
    };

// Works fine
    some_bar.foo = some_foo;

    return 0;
}
```

Both GCC and Clang accept it.

Am I missing something or does this piece of code exposes a compiler bug ?

**EDIT :** Duplicate: [Initializing struct within another struct using designated initializer causes compile error in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707402/initializing-struct-within-another-struct-using-designated-initializer-causes-co)

Comment: Is this example minimal (i.e. does the problem go away if you remove some members of these `struct`s)?

Comment: In case you didn't see it in the link: *A fix for this issue has been checked into the compiler sources. The fix should show up in the future release of Visual C++.* Perhaps this works with the new CTP?

Comment: @PatrickCollins This is a simplified example, the error first showed with `D2D1_SIZE_U` and `D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES` from <d2d1.h>

Comment: @chris Just saw. The link seemed dead on my side of the internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a [known bug](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805981/msvc-2013-c99-designated-initializers-cannot-initialize-unions-within-structs). It is said to be fixed in the next version of MSVC.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, the bug is still present in VS14 CTP 4.

**EDIT:** This bug has been fixed in VS2015 CTP 5.